# [simple issue]: import .net file (word/occurences) into cytoscape...which attributes are which?

Tags: nlp, text-processing, cytoscape

I took a corpus of text and put it into VosViewer to create a network for me. When I import this .net file into gephi, it works fine: I get a semantic network. Though I'm a little stuck for what attributes to select to import into cytoscape. Here is a CSV file of the network (.net import wouldn't work), and I just need to know which column to select as what.

Each column has the option of being imported as one of the following:

- Source Node
- Interaction type
- Edge Attribute
- Source Node Attribute
- Target Node Attribute

[image: CSV File Attributes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to export your network from Gephi in GraphML format and then load it from Cytoscape. This will allow you to forget about the gory conversion details

Just go to `File>Export>Graph file` and select `GraphML` under the **Files of type:** option

Answer (score 0):

Is this the .net format you are using?
https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/pajek-net-format/

If so, then you can see that the format (like any network file format) requires at least two columns of node identifiers, i.e., source and target.  Your screenshot clearly shows the first columns "id" along with some node attributes. The column headers for "weight" and "cluster" are not as clear. My naive guess is that the "weight (occurrences)" column is actually the second list of "target" node ids and the "weight (co-occurrences)" is an edge attribute. But this is just a guess!

If you can deduce the meaning of the columns in your file, then it's a simple matter to assign and import them into Cytoscape for .net or any tabluar file format.

Hope this helps!